# Could not load type from assembly exception in mono

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin-studio

I am new to c# and mono. and I encountered a strange question.
I have 2 projects in my solution. and one is dependent on another one called CoreLogic. I've already set up the dependency and the compilation is successful. However, when I run it and sent it a request, the program throws an exception like:

> server Error: Could not load type 'Logic.RedisStorage' from assembly
>   'CoreLogic, Version=1.0.5750.32870, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

the strangest thing is that I can see the Logic.RedisStorage class is present in the assembly CoreLogic of xamarin studio. but the program still complains. So, what is wrong here?
[image]

**EDIT:**
I've tried to re-add the dependency of CoreLogic, but it turns out no luck. here is what the mono has complained:
[image]

the assembly version does match what server is dependent(I can not upload imgs right now, so check following link for detail):

https://www.evernote.com/l/APWLUXOQa5pAxrm3MUZDhxZ88KkJ2Y5bhl0

Answer (score 0):

These cases occur because of mismatch of version number of Dll's references.

Rebuild your CoreLogic and Remove the refrence of CoreLogic and again add the reference.

Comment: my reference to CoreLogic is a project reference,  not a dll reference.  when I rebuild my solution, CoreLogic will be rebuilt before other project. anyway, I will try what you said later when I am at work.

Comment: hi @amit, it seems not working. I remove the CoreLogic dependency and rebuild CoreLogic and add back the CoreLogic dependency, the program still complains on the same thing.

Comment: That should not happen. This error is definitely because of different version of DLL. I would suggest to check the path of dll you have pointed to. It's quite possible you build the project in different configuration and pointing the dll in reference from some other location. Or check in the configuration manager if build configurations are same(quite possible that dll was build in x64 and you're using in x86)

Comment: Can you take backup of this dll and delete it and again rebuild your CoreLogic project and check if the dll gets created at the same place

Comment: when I run the program, I can see it from cosole that it Loaded the assembly from: /Users/ze/blitzfarm/Server/bin/Debug/CoreLogic.dll, and I've checked the version number using 'monodis --assembly', it really matches the assembly version number shown in the Assembly Browser. For your second suggestion, I've found that my main project targets at x86,and CoreLogic  targets ant All CPU, is that the cause?

Comment: confirmed, after rebuild the solution the CoreLogic.dll is recreated.

Comment: That might be the cause. bacuse x86 is supported for 32 bit and Any CPU works for both 32 and 64 bit. and when your project was getting build it didnt find the suitable dll for 64 bit platform. (Though in some cases it doesn't matter)

Comment: still no luck. I've changed both project's platform to Any CPU, the problem still exist.