# Nunit cannot load type of dependent reference on runtime in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin, nunit

happy sunday. I'm having an issue running a test in NUnit using an object whose base type is defined in a dependent reference in another project, in Xamarin Studio. The NUnit test runner can't load the type for some reason. I'm using NUnit 2.6.4 as 3 is not supported in XS yet.

Here's a snapshot of the solution setup:
[image]

Here's the definition of ExtendedService:
[image]

As you can see it inherits from the MobileServiceClient base type which is defined in the Windows.Azure.MobileServices assembly.

When I try to run a simple test using the ExtendedService object like this:

```
[Test()]
public void TestCase()
{
    var service = new ExtendedService();
}
```

I get a runtime error:
System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'TestApp.Mobile.ExtendedService' from assembly 'TestApp.Mobile', Version=1.0.5944.15805, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

It doesn't make sense because the compiler forces me to add the Windows.Azure.MobileServices reference in the test project because it knows it needs the dependent type in order to create ExtendedService.

The issue is well defined here:
[Could not load type from assembly exception in mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841767/could-not-load-type-from-assembly-exception-in-mono)
with no solution.

I can confirm that the issue does not occur in Visual Studio.

Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated!
Thanks guys.

Comment: What sort of project is TestApp.Mobile?

Comment: PCL 4.5 - Profile 78